# Nested navigation with in createMaterialTopTabNavigation.... how?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new to react-native, I have created `createMaterialTopTabNavigation` -- i.e, Login & Signup.

In my `LoginScreen` there is another screen `ForgotPassword` IDK how can I navigate to `ForgotPassword` screen from `LoginScreen` while I have only created one navigation i.e, `CreateMaterialTopTabNavigation`

[image: Route.js and the screenShot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createStackNavigator` as main navigation and `createMaterialTopTabNavigation` as first config that will execute.

try this,

```
...//your old navigators
const stack  =  createStackNavigator({
  tab:AppTabNavigator,
  forgotPassword:...// your forgot password screen
})
```

and then if you're using react-navigation@3.x then you need to wrap this stack in `appContainer` and export it.

Comment: I did tried this but it gives error -- The Component of route 'tab' must be a React component.